# Entity Framework Core - Use In Memory Database and fill with fake data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, startup

I'm stuck on how to add the DBContext in the `Startup.cs`. I have the following which doesn't work (but I was finally able to get it to compile). How can I reduce this to using the `options` I define and using that in my `using` statement. Obviously I don't want to define two different databases, but this was the only way I could get it to compile. If I'm approaching this the wrong way, please let me know. Here is a sample from `ConfigureServices()` in `Startup.cs`

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApiContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Appointments");
services.AddDbContext<ApiContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Test"));
using (var context = new ApiContext(options.Options))
{
     //Create Fake Data
     DataGenerator.GenerateData(context);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add fake data to MemoryDatabase,you can do as following.

In your `startup`:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApiContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase());
        //...
    }
    //To add data to the in-memory database when the application starts up, add some code to the Configure method:

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        //...
        var scopeeee = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope();
        var context = scopeeee.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApiContext>();
        AddTestData(context);
        //...
    }

    private static void AddTestData(ApiContext context)
    {
        //add fake data
        //.....
        context.Add(model);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked.  May I ask why I had to create scope to access my context?

Comment: You cannot create a scoped service instance from the root provider. The root provider is the root service provider that exists outside of service scopes. As such, it cannot resolve services that should only be consumed within service scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to create a context during `ConfigureServices`. There are other command line tools, like ef core, that will create your service provider for other reasons.

Instead I recommend you create an `IHostedService`, create a service scope and then perform your initialisation.